# Print past 6 month names from current month in Java

Tags: java, java-8

I need to print the past 6 month name from current month.

For example, when run in April 2016, I need to print: nov(2015), dec(2015), jan(2016), feb(2016), march(2016), april(2016)

```
Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM YYYY");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

String[] thisAndLastFiveMonths = new String[6];
for (int i = 0; i < thisAndLastFiveMonths.length; i++) {
    thisAndLastFiveMonths[i] = formatter.format(c.getTime());
    c.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
    System.out.println(c);
```

Comment: What is your question?

If the code you posted doesn't work, what does it do?

Providing this information will help us help you

Answer (score 8):

Using the [Java Time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), you can construct a [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) object representing the current year-month and call [`minusMonths`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html#minusMonths-long-) to subtract a number of months.

Then, you can get the textual representation of the month name with [`Month.getDisplayName(style, locale)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html#getDisplayName-java.time.format.TextStyle-java.util.Locale-). The given [`TextStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/TextStyle.html) is used to style the output; you can use [`SHORT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/TextStyle.html#SHORT) for your case:

> Short text, typically an abbreviation. For example, day-of-week Monday might output "Mon".

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 5; i >= 0; i--) {
        YearMonth date = YearMonth.now().minusMonths(i);
        String monthName = date.getMonth().getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(monthName + "(" + date.getYear() + ")");
    }
}
```

prints, when run in April 2016:

```
Nov(2015)
Dec(2015)
Jan(2016)
Feb(2016)
Mar(2016)
Apr(2016)
```